# testing grails iterative taglibs that use variables in body

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, taglib

I have a fair simple taglib like this (query is simplified for the sake of example):

```
def toptopics = { attrs, body ->
    def topics = Topic.executeQuery("from Topic")

    topics.each { topic -> 
        out << body(topic:topic)
    }
}
```

Then I use it in the gsp as follows:

```
    <g:toptopics>
        <li><a href="#">${topic.name}</a></li> 
    </g:toptopics>
```

Then I'm trying to write a test for it (code below):

```
void setUp() {
    taglib = new MySampleTagLib()
}

void test_each_in_collection() {
    assertEquals("tag 1;tag 2", taglib.toptopics() { "${topic.name};" })
}
```

But it keeps failing. The test output complain about "No such property: topic for class: MySampleTagLibTests

For some reason it's trying to evalute ${topic.name} before passing the string to the taglib. I've tried escaping the dollar sing with no success. Any tips on this?

Answer (score 0):

To test a taglib, you should extend `TagLibUnitTestCase`. When you use this class you don't instantiate your tag class directly (as in the code above), but instead an instance is made available to you through the `tagLib` property. For example, let's assume I want to test the `repeat` tag of `FooTagLib`. This tag takes a single attribute and expects the tag to have a body that uses variables.

```
class FooTagLibTests extends TagLibUnitTestCase {

  FooTagLibTests() {
    // This line isn't necessary in this case because the test class is in the same package 
    // as the tag class and named ${TagLib}Tests
    super(FooTagLib)
  }

  void testRepeat() {

    def someText = 'blah'

    // tagLib references an instance of FooTagLib. Invoke the bar tag passing it attribute
    // values and a body
    tagLib.repeat(times: '2') {
      "body $someText "
    }

    // compare the expected and actual output
    assertEquals 'body someText body someText ', tagLib.out.toString()
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work on grails 1.3.5? Also, if $someText is defined inside the taglib, why you need to declare it in the test? In my case even using TagLibUnitTestCase it keeps failing with the same message.

Comment: If you show the code and error message maybe I'll be able to help you